# How to instatiate an HTML template below a Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a template selling website and want to add a navbar above the HTML content of the template. I have created a separate HTML file where I defined navbar, and I call the HTML file when the end user previews the template. The theme also uses the Bootstrap CSS, so it's displaying below the navbar, which I called from the initial HTML file. I've the following in the first HTML file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top editbar">
```

and this in the template file:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
```

CSS:

```
.editbar {
    height: 48px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(22, 45, 61, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1450;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) top;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What do you want help with? What is displaying below the navbar?

Comment: Yes. I want to display below the first navbar. I mean I want the whole html file of template below the navbar of first file.

Comment: Do you mean it's not positioning correctly? Where is it currently displaying? Would you be able to post a screenshot of how it looks at the moment?

Comment: I want something like this http://themeforest.net/item/ap-alaska-shopify-responsive-theme/full_screen_preview/14778442 in this buy menu goes on top and below the page contents.

Comment: Can you post the CSS at all?

Comment: margin-top://navbar height

Comment: .editbar {
  height: 48px;
   position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(22, 45, 61, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1450;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) top;
     }

Comment: @DanWhite: I'll have to do this to all the template files, I want a general css which can be called in first html file.

Comment: You should use an iframe.  Even your example (themeforest) is using an iframe.  That will isolate your CSS and javascript of one document from the other.

Comment: Thanks that helped.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer,

I did it with the help of css.

Just added a class to this navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top template" role="banner">
```

And added the following in the css:

```
.template {
    top: 44px;
 }
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Position your `nav` using the `position:fixed;` CSS property. This takes the div out of the normal DOM sequence, placing it above the DOM. You can then use `left` and `top` properties to position it at the top of your viewport.

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  height:30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}
```

Since the `nav` probably overlaps your main content area, offset your main content block by the combined height and padding of your `nav` element. In my example we have a height of 30px + padding of 10px, 40px total of space. You would offset your main content by 40px so that it is visible below your fixed header.

I made a Codepen example you can check out as well:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/KzxeKZ